# Magento 2 : Image Validation is not working in back end form

Tags: adminhtml, magento2.2.2, image-upload

I have a custom module which manage to upload the banners.

Everything working fine except **image validation**.

Below is my code for the image in

> **app/code/E25media/Bannersmanager/Block/Adminhtml/Banners/Edit/Tab/Main.php**

```
<?php
namespace E25media\Bannermanager\Block\Adminhtml\Banners\Edit\Tab;

class Main extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Generic implements \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Tab\TabInterface
{
   /* -- some code here */ 
protected function _prepareForm()
{ 
     /* -- some code here */ 
     $fieldset->addType('image', '\E25media\Bannermanager\Block\Adminhtml\Banners\Helper\Image');

$fieldset->addField('banner_image_mobile', 'image', array(
'name'      => 'banner_image_mobile',
'class'     => 'required-entry required-file',
'label' => __('Mobile Banner Image'),
'title' => __('Mobile Banner Image'),
'required'  => true,
'disabled'  => $isElementDisabled));

  /* -- some code here */ 
 }
```

My form file upload is look like this.
[image]

But i can submit the form without uploading the image.

How to validate the image file ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this.
**Use javascript to add the class.**

```
$fieldset->addField( 
        'banner_image_mobile', 
        'image',
        [ 
        'name' => 'banner_image_mobile', 
        'label' => __('Mobile Banner Image'), 
        'title' => __('Mobile Banner Image'),             
        'note' => __('Size: 164px x 24px, Allowed File Types : (JPG,JPEG,PNG), Max Size:2MB.'), 
        'path'=> $model->getImagePath(),
        'required' => true, 
        'value' => $model->getImagePath()
        ] 
        )->setAfterElementHtml('
        <script>
            require([
                 "jquery",
            ], function($){
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    if($("#page_banner_image_mobile").attr("value")){
                        $("#page_banner_image_mobile").removeClass("required-file");
                    }else{
                        $("#page_banner_image_mobile").addClass("required-file");
                    }
                    $( "#page_banner_image_mobile" ).attr( "accept", "image/x-png,image/gif,image/jpeg,image/jpg,image/png" );
                });
              });
       </script>
    ');
```

Comment: thanks for your answer.I am getting this error
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''disabled'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ')' in D:\xampp\htdocs\tork\app\code\E25media\Bannermanager\Block\Adminhtml\Banners\Edit\Tab\Main.php on line 159

Comment: check my updated answer and compare with your current code.

Comment: @Mujahidh still getting error?

Comment: still allow me to submit the form without upload the image

Comment: I think there is a problem with your field id mentioned in script, alert in JavaScript code and check  field id is correct or not, because this code working for me.

Comment: i checked , id was page_banner_image_mobile, but still i can submit the form without uploading the image

Comment: Make sure, if you give $form->setHtmlIdPrefix(); then also include prefix name with ID.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77236/discussion-between-mujahidh-and-chirag-patel).