# How to hide specific days from admin form calendar field in magento 2

Tags: magento2, forms, jquery, form-validation

I want to disable week days **(Saturday & Sunday)** in admin form calendar field. check below screen-shoot.

[image]

Below is my field code.

```
$fieldsetDirector->addField(
        'attendance', 'date',
        [
        'name' => 'attendance',
        'label' => __('Attendance'),
        'title' => __('Attendance'),
        'date_format' => 'yyyy-MM-dd',
        'id' => 'attendance'
        ]
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the DatePicker so no weekend is selectable

```
$fieldsetDirector->addField(
        'attendance', 'date',
        [
        'name' => 'attendance',
        'label' => __('Attendance'),
        'title' => __('Attendance'),
        'date_format' => 'yyyy-MM-dd',
        'id' => 'attendance'
        ]
    )->setAfterElementHtml(
        '<script>
            require([
                 "jquery",
            ], function($){
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    $( "#attendance" ).datepicker({
                      beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends
                    });
                });
              });
       </script>'
    );
```

Comment: How to implement this script in my code? i know how to disable days in calendar, but issue is how to implement this script in my code

Comment: i update your answer, please check here how script implement to magento backend form.

Comment: Thanks man for converting JQ to mAgento Implementation.

Comment: For more reference check this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/225226/magento-2-image-validation-is-not-working-in-back-end-form/225243#225243